# my for loop not is not executing?

Tags: javascript

this is an assignment in free code camp, my problem is my for loop is not iterating, it's a function returned from filter method, i need to loop through the extra parameters aside from the initial array[0] to compare if it match and remove.

the result of this code is 1,3,1,3 which i want to be 1,1.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    var p = arguments.length; // arr  length
    var r = arguments; // 
    function argScope(item) {
        debugger;
        for(var a =1; a<=p; a++) { // start iterate at 1, 0 is the initial array I want to remove elements
            if(item == r[a]) { // this is true at 1 so 2 is removed, but loop doesn't execute
                return false;
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        }
    }

    var v = arr.filter(function(item,index,array) {
    debugger;
    return argScope(item); // call a function for the scope

    });
    return v;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); // function call
```

help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {

  function argScope(item) {
    debugger;
    for (var a = 1; a < arr.length; a++)
      if (item == arr[a]) return false;
    return true;
  }

  return arr[0].filter(function(item) {
    debugger;
    return argScope(item); // call a function for the scope
  });
}

var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
var filteredArray = destroyer([myArray, 2, 3]);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: I have done this code but our difference are the braces, didn't know this works, but I want to ask why does this not work with braces?

Comment: I assume you're talking about the braces in the for loop? It will work with braces of course, but you returned the item in the else clause; I returned true after the loop finishes.

Answer (score 3):

You return from your loop after exactly one iteration.
Maybe you meant:

```
for(var a =1; a<=p; a++) { // start iterate at 1, 0 is the initial array I want to remove elements
    if(item == r[a]) { // r and a is not set, value is only set after 
        return item;
    }
}
return false;
```